# Along what curve does a circle roll down the fastest?

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418486/along-what-curve-does-an-ellipse-roll-down-the-fastest) MO question, I stated that a circle rolls down the fastest along a cycloid curve - as shown by Johan Bernoulli, thereby solving the Brachistochrone problem.

However, as user Manfred Weis pointed out, his solution involved finding the curve of fastest descent not for a circle, but for a point.

Therefore, I was wondering if the solution has also been found for an actual circle. The solution probably is not very different from the cycloid found by Bernoulli for the point, but I wonder how it differs and how it takes into account the circle's radius $r$.

Comment: An example solution for a point mass is here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html. For a a circular hoop or sphere rolling without slipping, you just have to account for the rotational kinetic energy so you'd have $$\frac12mv^2+\frac12I\omega^2=mgy$$ with $\omega=\frac vr$, so the solution would be similar and you'd still have a cycloid

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thank you. I believe that in the following paper by Akulenko a solution is presented, as pointed out by user Timothy Budd on MO: https://sci-hub.se/10.1016/j.jappmathmech.2009.08.015

Comment: OK so does the article you cite answer your question?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I suspect it does - still need to read it more thoroughly and carefully